Windows 11 disappeared from BIOS after installing Arch with GRUB
I've been using NixOS with a dual boot setup for Windows 11, with each OS installed on its own drive. To switch between them, I've been using the BIOS boot priority.
However, last week I reverted to Arch Linux with GRUB (EFI), and now Windows has disappeared from the BIOS. I tried running sudo os-prober, but nothing was detected. I also uncommented GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false in /etc/default/grub and reran sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg (with the Windows partition mounted), which output the following:
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.

However, nothing has worked, and Windows is still not appearing in the GRUB menu.
Here's the output of sudo fdisk -l:
Disk /dev/sdb: 111.79 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Disk model: XrayDisk 120GB  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D21C97E4-1AAF-42B6-8273-48C5F5569216

Device     Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048     34815     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdb2  34816 234440703 234405888 111.8G Microsoft basic data

Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 476.94 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk model: WALRAM 512G                             
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: ADBDC778-9E86-475D-A315-CCCA41A224CF

Device             Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048    2099199   2097152     1G EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2   2099200  316671999 314572800   150G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p3 316672000 1000214527 683542528 325.9G Linux filesystem

/dev/sdb2 is my Windows partition, and /dev/nvme0n1* contains my Arch Linux partitions.

Your sdb disk doesn't look like it has any EFI System Partition of its own; just the C: partition and the 16 MB placeholder. So it's possible that when you removed NixOS' bootloader from the nvme0n1p1 partition you also removed Windows' BOOTMGR with it.
If you're sure you have bootmgfw.efi in the EFI System Partition, use the efibootmgr tool to re-add it to the firmware's boot menu.
Otherwise, boot into some WinPE system – any Windows 10/11 installation USB will do; hit Shift-F10 to access Cmd – and use bcdboot.exe to re-install a copy of BOOTMGR. (This is the equivalent of grub-install and grub-mkconfig; it copies BOOTMGR from C:\Windows and adds it to the EFI boot menu.)
Optional: Create a new EFI System Partition on sdb and install the Windows boot files there, making the two disks independent.
